# Regular Expression for paired brackets

Tags: regex, regex-negation

The Input Line goes like this (just a part of it):

```
[[Text Text Text]][[text text text]]asdasdasdasda[[asdasdasdasd]]
```

What I want is to list all matches wherein text enclosed in a pair of `[[` and `]]`.
I did try several patterns, but all fails when a unclosed `[[` or `]]` is within the input line.  For example:

```
[[text[[text text TEXT text]]
```

Also, what if a single bracket exist within the input line, like:

```
[[text [text] text TEXT text]]
```

The regex pattern I used was:

```
\[\[[^\[\[]*\]\]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\[\[(?:(?!\[\[|\]\]).)*\]\]
```

matches  `[[<anything>]]`, where `<anything>` may not contain double brackets but everything else. You might need to set the `DOTALL` option of your regex engine to allow the dot to match newlines.

It will match `[[match [this] text]]` in

```
[[don't match this [[match [this] text]] don't match this]]
```

**Explanation:**

```
\[\[     # Match [[
(?:      # Match...
 (?!     #  (unless we're right at the start of
  \[\[   #   [[
 |       #  or
  \]\]   #   ]]
 )       #  )
 .       # ...any character
)*       # Repeat any number of times
\]\]     # Match ]]
```

Caveat: It will match `[[match [this]]` in the text `[[match[this]]]` because regexes can't count.

Answer (score 2):

What to do with unclosed or single brackets is up to your specification. Until then

```
\[\[([^\]]|\][^\]])*\]\]
```

works for me (where the whole of the two problematic strings are matched.

Comment: @sweaver2112 You mean for a generic regex across the various implementations? The above was tested with .NET.

Comment: would there be any where escaping it would hurt?  your pattern works, but on regexr it did not until i escaped the ]. it is, after all, a special char and the regex engine may not be smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the backslash for the `]` after the `|` and I've added them for the classes too.