# Regular Expressions (Normal OR Nested Brackets)

Tags: regex, nested, pcre, brackets

So I'm completely new to the overwhelming world of Regex. Basically, I'm using the Gedit API to create a new custom language specification (derived from C#) for syntax-highlighting (for DM from Byond). In escaped characters in DM, you have to use **[variable]** as an escaping syntax, which is simple enough. However, it could also be nested, such as **[array/list[index]]** for instance. (It could be nested infinitely.) I've looked through the other questions, and when they ask about nested brackets they only mean exclusively nested, whereas in this case it could be either/or.

Several attempts I've tried:

- `\[.*\]` produces the result "Test **[Test[Test] Test]Test[Test]** Test"
- `\[.*?\]` produces the result "Test **[Test[Test]** Test]Test **[Test]** Test"
- `\[(?:.*)\]` [produces](http://regex101.com/r/rS7nX5) the result "Test **[Test[Test] Test]Test[Test]** Test"
- `\[(?:(?!\[|\]).)*\]` [produces](http://regex101.com/r/eI6uT8) the result "Test [Test**[Test]** Test]Test**[Test]** Test".  This is derived from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9580978/2303154 but like mentioned above, that only matches if there are no brackets inside.

Obviously I've no real idea what I'm doing here in more complex matching, but at least I understand more of the basic operations from other sources.

Comment: Carefully reading [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) makes the world of regex a lot less overwhelming. Also, nested structures are usually where regex approaches crumble - only .NET's regex flavour and PCRE support structures that can deal with indefinite nesting.

Comment: Unfortunately since it's an API I don't think I can differentiate and just have to use what Gedit has the XML do for matching, ;-;. And yeah, that was one of the main tutorials I've been looking at.

Comment: Your 3rd and 4th attempts were syntactically malformed (thus matching nothing in your Test string).  I corrected them.  #3: Your version `\[(?:.*))\]` has a duplicate closing bracket.  The correction `\[(?:.*)\]` is equivalent to #1.  The _non-capturing group_ `(?:…)` serves no apparent purpose here.  #4: Your version `\[?:(?!\[|\]).*\]` sports part of the non-capturing group syntax - `?:` - without the corresponding brackets `(…)`.  `(?:(?!\[|\]).)` can be simplified to `[^\]\[]` (the backslashes are optional when listing the charclass's chars in this order: `[^][]`).

Comment: What do you mean by "only exclusively nested brackets" vs. "either/or"?  By "exclusively" do you mean something like `[[[Test]]]`, whereas `[x[[Test]]]` would be 'non-exclusive'?

Answer (score 1):

From [@Chaos7Theory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303154/chaos7theory):

Upon reading [GtkSourceView's Specification Reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/lang-reference.html), I've figured out that it uses PCRE specifically. I then used that as a lead.

Digging into it and through trial-and-error, I got it to work with:

```
\[(([^\[\]]*|(?R))*)\]
```

I hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: @Chaos7Theory: Thanks for Doing The Research on this and sharing the solution!  @ Alex: Thanks for moving it to a proper Answer!